# Getting a type for a template instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following situation:

I have a object of type `MyClass`, which has a method to cast itself to its base class. The class includes a typedef for its base class and a method to do the upcast.

```
template <class T, class B>
class BaseClass;

template <class T>
class NoAccess;

template <class T>
class MyClass : public BaseClass<T, NoAccess<T> >
{
  private:
    typedef BaseClass<T, NoAccess<T> > base;

  public:
    base &to_base();
};
```

I need to pass the result of a `base` call to a functor `Operator`:

```
template <class Y>
class Operator
{
   Operator(Y &x);
};

Operator<???> op(myobject.to_base());
```

Is there a easy way to fill the `???` provided that I do not want to use NoAccess?

Comment: I don't think `myobject.base` is valid syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a factory function to use type deduction:

```
template< class Y >
Operator<Y> create_operator( Y &y ) {
    return Operator<Y>( y );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I see three possibilities:

1. make `MyClass<T,B>::base` a `public` identifier
2. change your operator and make the constructor a template using type-erasure (might be hard):
   `class Operator { template<class Y> Operator(Y &x); }`
3. move the code creating the `Operator` object into its own function template:
   `template<typename T> Operator<T> createOperator(const T& base)`
   `{return Operator<T>(base);}`

Answer (score 2):

You can make the typedef public:

```
Operator<MyClass<type>::base> op(myobject.to_base());
```